# How to remove controls from groupbox in?

Tags: c#, dynamic, groupbox

I am dynamically creating buttons in groupbox, so when I press second button, it should display different set of buttons in same groupbox, so I need to delete earlier buttons in order to get new ones, am I thinking right or is there any other way.

Thanks

Comment: Both WPF and WinForms have a `GroupBox` control. Which are you talking about?

Comment: I havent tried anything , and its a WINFORM

Answer (score 2):

I used these codes:

```
int c = groupBox6.Controls.Count;

for (int i = c - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    groupBox6.Controls.Remove(groupBox6.Controls[i]);
```

and this has worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)

```
var x = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(c => c.Name == "button1").FirstOrDefault();
groupBox1.Controls.Remove(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to clear your groupbox:

```
groupbox.Controls.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop now works for me. I tried a foreach(Control ctl in ParameterFrame) and it only removed half of the controls. I'm adding my controls two at a time in a method like this:

ParameterFrame.Controls.Add(txt);
ParameterFrame.Controls.Add(lbl);

For some reason the foreach() would only remove the first of the two that I added. In the above case only the txt (textboxes) would get removed. If I switched the order and added the Labels first, the foreach would only remove the labels and leave the textboxes sitting there. Why I don't know. Though as I said the regular for loop removed them all.